# tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_loss` which is not available

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to use EarlyStopping in Grid Search for Hyperparameter optimisation by monitoring val_loss. But the current code will throw an error saying val_loss metric is not available. Shouldn't the cross-validation in GridSearchCV provide the validation set to the model for calculating validation loss?

I am aware that this code will work fine if I add `validation_split=0.1` to KerasRegressor but I don't really want to make the training data any smaller.

I do have a X_test dataset reserved, but I don't want it to be used to do Hyperparameter optimization.

```
nn_early_stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    min_delta = 0.001,
    patience = 20,
    restore_best_weights = True
)

model_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
        ('model', KerasRegressor(model=createNN, epochs=200, callbacks=[nn_early_stopping]))
    ])

param_grid = {
    'model__batch_size': [32, 64],
    'model__model__units': [16, 21],
    'model__model__activation': ['relu', 'sigmoid', 'softmax', 'tanh']
}

model_optimiser = GridSearchCV(model_pipeline, param_grid, cv=3, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')

optimised_model = model_optimiser.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: There's no `val_loss` metric because you're not using validation data. Either pass validation data to `.fit()` or use the `validation_split` parameter to have the function create the validation data for you. You say you don't want to pull validation data from training data, but you don't want to use test data either...those are your only options if you want to use `val_loss`, otherwise, use a different metric. or maybe get the validation data from your test set if the labels are present too.

Comment: Also, cross-validation doesn't necessarily mean you'll get validation data. At minimum, you get your training and testing indices. You still need to define your validation data. For example, sklearn kfold function only gives training and test indices. You then make your validation data from the training set (usually).